# Best way to Create Low File Size GIFs in Premiere Pro

Tags: animation, video, adobe-premiere

I want to use Premiere Pro to create small sized (300kb or less) GIFs. The typical set up would be a static image that doesn't move, and then an animated part (from a video) inside the static image. What would be the best way to accomplish this without going over the size budget?

[image]

Comment: If the video is of a "real-world" situation and you have any control over how it's made, do all you can to keep the camera still. If the camera is moving around, even a little, there will be no image pixels that will stay the same from one frame to the next; the more "static" pixels there are, the more the video can be compressed w/o loss of quality.

Answer (score 3):

First. Premiere is not the best tool to make a small size gif. Premiere is a video editor. You need a compositor.

Regarding a program, I use Hit Film which is free, and I also use Blender for 2D animation, (also free). If you want, you can use After Effects.

When using Blender you need to use emission as the shader.

Second. You need to plan your palette. This is probably the most important thing to reduce file size while maintaining a good quality.

The flat style is very good for an animated gif, and this is actually what revived the format. Use flat style and do not dither the image.

Export your animation-sequence as still PNG and assemble and export on another program, for example, Gimp.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread to try and find the answer myself, and have decided to use [LiceCap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) - an openSource screen capture gif creator - I just used it to create an 8.5MB file from a 16 second video clip, though I'm sure if I tweaked the settings and made it smaller could have saved more space

Comment: So your answer to the question in the title is "do not use Premiere Pro"?

Comment: pretty much, yes. Like most of the other comments in this thread also said, Adobe Premiere Pro is probably not the best software to use to create GIFs, even though it is possible. I'm just adding another potential option which I found useful and may be desirable for others due to the other benefits that come with having a quick universal screen-cap gif-creator in one's bag of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

File > Export > Media. In the new window, under "Format" select "Animated GIF"

You'll then have to play with the quality to get 300kb or less. The size depends on the length and how many unique colours you have in your video. Premiere isn't really the best place to make animated GIFs, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

A compositor like "Adobe After Effects" is good Choice for creating GIFs, First Export Your Animation in Looseness AVI or MOV format from Premier Pro, so there will be no degradation of quality, if you want your GIF to be transparent, export your media with Alpha Channel for that **[Refer this article](https://theblog.adobe.com/exporting_video_with_an_alpha/)**.

1) You can also export as JPEG sequence and then Merge those photos in Photoshop to create GIF, **[Refer this tutorial from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/how-to/make-animated-gif.html)**.

2) You can use Adobe After Effects Plugin Called **[GIFGUN](https://aescripts.com/gifgun/)**, take exported loosless/alpha channel video in After effects and this plugin do it's work, there is few options that will bring your GIF size under 300 kb, or else if GIF size is bigger then you can Compress it Online with tools like [Online GIF optimizer](https://ezgif.com/optimize).

Answer (score 0):

When I used After Effects it was only saving me 2mb. So I made the clip in Prem Pro then used https://ezgif.com/optimize to compress it and it went down from 22mb to 4.5mb.

I'm sure there's a better way to do it but saved me installing and learning a new programme

Answer (score 0):

Use shortcuts on your iPhone. It's so easy.
Export your short video clip from Premiere Pro.
Airdrop the clip to your phone.
Go to your Shortcuts app on your iPhone.
Search for 'Video to GIF while in the Gallery tab, then Tap Add Shortcut in the result provided.
Run the shortcut by tapping its card in the My Shortcuts tab.